# Get vpcID and dedicated loadbalancerID in Mulesoft Anypoint platform cloudhub

Tags: mulesoft, cloudhub, anypoint-platform

I want to run this command for retrieveing ciphers of the cloudhub dedicated loadbalancer in Mulesoft.

[https://anypoint.mulesoft.com/cloudhub/api/organizations/{myORgID}/vpcs/{myVPCID}/loadbalancers/{myLoadbalancerID}](https://anypoint.mulesoft.com/cloudhub/api/organizations/%7BmyORgID%7D/vpcs/%7BmyVPCID%7D/loadbalancers/%7BmyLoadbalancerID%7D).

I have added the bearer authorization header.

I have the organisation ID but I cannot find the myPVCID and cannot find the myLoadbalancerID.

I allready tried it with anypoint-cli:
cloudhub vpc describe production-netherlands-vpc 
cloudhub load-balancer describe production-netherlands

But this only gives me a name and details about the configuration, but it does not give me the loadbalancerID and vpcID which is something in this format 24ad4887e4b0623a74a35feb.(just an example numbers are changed because of security) 
Spent hours to find out but with no success.

When I try it and use the names of the vpc and loadbalancer instead of the IDs then the query in curl of postman returns something like this.

{
"status": 404,
"message": "null for uri: null"
}

I can run this command without a problem, but this is not what I need:
[https://anypoint.mulesoft.com/cloudhub/api/organizations/{myOrgID}/loadbalancers/ciphersuites](https://anypoint.mulesoft.com/cloudhub/api/organizations/%7BmyOrgID%7D/loadbalancers/ciphersuites)

So how to resolve the vpcID and the loadbalancerID ?

Answer (score 0):

yes I have found it. These vpcId and the loadbalancerID are available in the URL of the Anypoint cloudhub web console.
Maybe somebody else find this info usefull, because these ID's are hard to find.
Strange Mulesoft is not publishing them with the Anypoint-CLI cloudhub vpc describe command.